# Trouble creating a new invitation record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't seem to figure why the create method in my invitations controller will not create a new record. I have only sent params over from a form before and in this case it is from a link_to. I think my problems source is coming from the view.

view:

```
<div class="title"> Invite <%= @user.name %> </div>
<div class="invitations"> Which event would you like to invite <%= @user.name %> to? </div>

<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <% @events.events.each do |f|  %>
  <div class="panel-body">
  <%= link_to f.title, controller: "invitations",
                       action: :create,
                       user_id: f.id,
                       method: :post %> </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

controller:

```
class InvitationsController < ApplicationController

def index
end 

def new 
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @events = current_user
    @invitation = Invitation.new
end

def create
  @invitation = Invitation.new(invitation_params)
  if @invitation.save 
    flash[:info] ="Invitation sent"
    redirect_to root_path
  else
  flash[:info] = "Something went wrong"
  redirect_to root_path 
  end 
end 

def show
end 

private

def invitation_params
  params.permit(:user_id)
end

end
```

routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'attendances/create'
  get 'invitations/create'
  resources :attendances
  resources :events
  resources :static_pages
  resources :users
  resources :invitations
  root 'static_pages#index'
  get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'

end
```

logs:

```
Started GET "/invitations/create?method=post&user_id=4" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-24 22:28:00 -0500
Processing by InvitationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"method"=>"post", "user_id"=>"4"}
Unpermitted parameter: :method
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.4ms)  rollback transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 1564ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're permitting only `user_id` in your `invitation_params`.

As the syntaxis for the link_to helper isn't valid, the `method: :post` is being added as parameters:

> Parameters: {"method"=>"post", "user_id"=>"4"}

Hence the message:

> Unpermitted parameter: :method

Try using the path instead specifying the controller and action in the link_to:

```
<%= link_to f.title, invitations_path(user_id: f.id), method: :post %>
```

This also works, but is more code:

```
<%= link_to user.name, { controller: 'users', action: 'create', user_id: f.id }, method: :post %>
```

This doesn't work:

```
<%= link_to user.name, users_path, { user_id: f.id, method: :post } %>
# => Unpermitted parameters: :_method, :authenticity_token
```

Comment: Unpermitted parameters: :_method, :authenticity_token

Comment: https://github.com/jmooree30/private-events if you would like to take a better look

Comment: Same error as my first comment, not sure what you changed.

Comment: By the content of your create method and checking your repo, you can use `<%= link_to 'ASD', invitations_path(user_id: 1), remote: true, method: :post %>`.

Comment: Although that worked, I'm really confused right now. I'm going to look this over.

Comment: Add the invitation require in your params, then send a hash with key invitation and { user_id: 1 } as value. Answer to your question, you're not working with params as needed.
`<%= link_to 'ASD', controller: 'invitations', action: 'create', method: :post, invitation: { user_id: 1 }%>` `params.require(:invitation).permit(:user_id)`.

Comment: So I'd like to know why we used the invitations_path which is for the index method and not the create method?

Comment: `invitations_path` handles also the create action if you specify the type of request, in that case POST, otherwise GET would be for the index action, take a look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions).

Comment: Awesome, before one of your edits you had remote: true, what did that do?

Comment: That created a request in JS format instead HTML, not sure on why it didn't have the _method and authenticity_token params, and also I'm not sure why your application does too, I tested on vanilla Rails 5.1.4 app and I hadn't problems.